# installing jupyterlab-latex gives nmp failed dependencies, Anaconda on WIndows 10

Tags: npm, anaconda, jupyter, conda

I try to install jupyterlab-latex on a fresh Anaconda installation, but "npm dependencies fail to install.

Firstly, using only conda:

```
install Anaconda3-2021.05-Windows-x86_64.exe
conda update anaconda
conda install -c anaconda jupyter
conda install -c conda-forge nodejs
conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
jupyter contrib nbextension install --system
conda install nbconvert=5.6.1   # known issue with template_path(s)
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab-latex
```

It reports a failed build.

```
[LabBuildApp] Building in C:\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab
[LabBuildApp] Node v16.6.1

[LabBuildApp] Yarn configuration loaded.
[LabBuildApp] Building jupyterlab assets (production, minimized)
[LabBuildApp] > node C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\staging\yarn.js install --non-interactive
[LabBuildApp] yarn install v1.21.1
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[2/5] Resolving packages...
[3/5] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@2.3.2: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.3.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[4/5] Linking dependencies...
warning "@jupyterlab/extensionmanager > react-paginate@6.5.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^16.0.0".
warning "@jupyterlab/json-extension > react-highlighter@0.4.3" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0".
warning "@jupyterlab/json-extension > react-json-tree@0.15.0" has unmet peer dependency "@types/react@^16.3.0 || ^17.0.0".
warning "@jupyterlab/vdom > @nteract/transform-vdom@4.0.16-alpha.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^16.3.2".
warning " > @lumino/coreutils@1.8.2" has unmet peer dependency "crypto@1.0.1".
warning "@jupyterlab/latex > pdfjs-dist@2.0.943" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0-alpha.0 || ^4.0.0".
warning "@jupyterlab/latex > pdfjs-dist > worker-loader@2.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0-alpha.0 || ^4.0.0".
warning "@jupyterlab/builder > @jupyterlab/buildutils > verdaccio > clipanion@3.0.1" has unmet peer dependency "typanion@*".
warning Workspaces can only be enabled in private projects.
warning Workspaces can only be enabled in private projects.
[5/5] Building fresh packages...
error C:\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\yjs: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node ./sponsor-y.js
Arguments: 
Directory: C:\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\yjs
Output:
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\yjs\sponsor-y.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.

[LabBuildApp] npm dependencies failed to install
[LabBuildApp] Traceback (most recent call last):

[LabBuildApp]   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\debuglog.py", line 48, in debug_logging
    yield

[LabBuildApp]   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\labapp.py", line 176, in start
    raise e

[LabBuildApp]   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\labapp.py", line 172, in start
    build(name=self.name, version=self.version,

[LabBuildApp]   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\commands.py", line 482, in build
    return handler.build(name=name, version=version, static_url=static_url,

[LabBuildApp]   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\commands.py", line 688, in build
    raise RuntimeError(msg)

[LabBuildApp] RuntimeError: npm dependencies failed to install

[LabBuildApp] Exiting application: JupyterLab
```

So, "npm dependencies failed to install". That file sponsor-y.js is missing; in fact, the whole folder staging is already missing.

I tried pip install jupyterlab-latex on a fresh Anaconda installation as well, but, then, the file C:\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules@fortawesome\fontawesome-free\attribution.js is missing.

I also tried from within Anaconda Navigator, but, then, Anaconda requests Jupyter Lab to be build manually. Result as above.

I have looked up the suggested website https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install, but yarn must be used behind the scene, and I don't know how to control its use by either conda or pip.

And why does it report a "The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module". I am working on an up-to-date Windows 10, 64 bit machine, where I have set up an administrator plus a few user accounts. It is directly connected to our internet provider, no proxy. The Anaconda installation is system-wide.

Comment: while this cannot answer your main question, it's worth mentioning that `fsevents@2.3.2: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.` happens because fsevents is only available for macOS. This is not a problem, and it says so: it "is an optional dependency".

Answer (score 0):

Well, Anaconda already installs Jupyter and Jupyter Lab. So, no need to repeat. Then,

```
npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
npm install attribution
```

was all it took. Don't know why the installation failed over those other npm packages this time, but the error messages were analogue to the original ones.